# Android: ListView's height doesn't equal its parent's height, but disapears

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` containing items. Each item's height wraps their content. However, the `ListView` disapears instead of showing its items by being expanded until the bottom side of its parent.

My question is: why?

Here are the layouts.

## The item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seals_list_item_amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seals_list_item_tags"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seals_list_item_amount" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/seals_list_item_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seals_list_item_tags"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/seal_empty" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

## The ListView, using parent's height

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/seals_main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/choose_seal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="@string/choose_seal" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/handle_publication_share_list_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Deleting and reposting your question after an hour usually isn't the best way to get answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170697/android-update-imageviews-height-if-the-imagebitmap-is-changed-with-the-height

Comment: The deleted question is bound to another problem, which *can* be bound to the one of this question. That's why I deleted it. Btw, for whom read the deleted question (you shoud edit your comment to remove it please): there **isn't** any changement of `ImageBitmap` in the current question.

Comment: everything looks fine except the height of imageView in your item, try something fix instead of wrap_content and test it again

Comment: The height of the image view of the item vary in function of the bitmap image of the image view. So I can't fix the height of the item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's all that's in your layout, then you don't really need a `ConstraintLayout` - a regular `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` should do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/seals_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/choose_seal" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/handle_publication_share_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you think it's because of the Constraint Layout?

Comment: That's my assumption. There might be a way to fix it while still using the `ConstraintLayout`, but a `LinearLayout` is just a much simpler and more straightforward solution.

Comment: Your assumption is good! Is it a bug that should be fixed by Google?